# SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER 00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g

```
create table hdate
(
hidate Date
);

insert into hdate values(2019-04-23);
```

how shall I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> insert into hdate values(2019-04-23);

You must pass the value using single quotes along with proper format mask and convert it into date using **TO_DATE**:

```
insert into hdate values( TO_DATE('2019-04-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD') );
```

Or, better use **ANSI Date literal** which uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

```
insert into hdate values(DATE '2019-04-23');
```

Comment: @sonalipatil Glad it helped. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!